# Combining access sql tables in a query side by side

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables containing different data, linked by a column "id", except the id is repeated multiple times
For example,

Table 1:

```
id  grade 
1   A        
1   C
```

Table 2:

```
Id  company
1   Alpha
1   Beta
1   Charlie
```

The number of rows would be inconsistent, table 1 may sometimes have more/less/equal rows compared to table 2. How am I able to combine/merge them into this outcome:

```
id  grade company
1   A     Alpha
1   C     Beta
1         Charlie
```

I am using Microsoft access' query.

Comment: Please add table definitions and sample data as text to the question together with your work in progress query.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)!

Comment: MySQL tag is valid (Backend is Oracle MySQL?)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and help, i have no idea how to add that block

Comment: Welcome. Your question is unclear because you've not explained the logic which gets you from those tables and data to the desired output - it doesn't look like there's an obvious field to join the tables on, so are you asking to just sort the tables and place them side-by-side? If so, you need to define what field(s) you want to sort each table on and explain how you want to handle a situation where the `id` field doesn't match on both tables, as you only show one `id` field in your desired output, but there is a separate `id` field in each table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain in MS Access.  But you can do it by using a subquery to generate sequence numbers.  Here is one method assuming that the rows are unique:

```
select id, max(grade) as grade, max(company) as company
from ((select id, grade, null as company,
              (select count(*)
               from table1 as tt1
               where tt1.id = t1.id and tt1.grade <= t1.grade
              ) as seqnum
       from table1 as tt1
      ) union all
      (select id, null as grade, company,
              (select count(*)
               from table2 as tt2
               where tt2.id = t2.id and tt2.company <= t1.company
              ) as seqnum
       from table2 as tt2
      )
     ) t12
group by id, seqnum;
```

This would be much simpler in almost any other database.